# Цели метрики в contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7, яндекс-метрика

Использую плагин Contact Form 7.
В нем есть вкладка "дополнительные настройки". Раньше вставлял туда  цель Метрики: 
`on_sent_ok:"yaCounterХХХХХХХХ.reachGoal(‘submit’);"`.
Сейчас плагин рекомендует `on_sent_ok` заменить событием `wpcf7mailsent`. Как правильно подключить это событие?

Answer (score 1):

> как правильно подключить это событие?

Возможно так получится:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  yaCounterХХХХХХХ.reachGoal('submit');
}, false );
```

Другой способ для Google Analytics есть в [документации](https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/).
Нужно добавить в `functions.php` активной темы:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

А из доп. настроек плагина удалить `on_sent_ok`.

(Для метрики нужно заменить js-скрипт)